# Is there a way to generate an alphanumeric string in lua?

Tags: string, random, lua

I want to generate a random alphanumeric string with a custom length in Lua. I'm using this as a password cracker to show my friends and I know Lua is a pretty fast language. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You'll probably want to iterate all alphanumeric strings of a certain length rather than generating random ones.

Comment: Lua is fine, but for a password cracker C or similar might be more appropriate. Allows for better memory management and multi threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Single-character manipulation of strings is a little bit fiddly in Lua, so perhaps the best method is to build an array of byte values corresponding to each character, then concatenate them together with a call to `string.char()`. I'm using `math.random()` to fetch random numbers here. You will probably want to call `math.randomseed(os.time())` at the top of your program unless you're not bothered about generating the same sequence of passwords every time.

The online Lua documentation is perfectly readable. You should take a look at the chapters on [strings](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html) and the [mathmatical library](https://www.lua.org/pil/18.html) (which includes the random number functions).

```lua
--[[ function returning a random alphanumeric string of length k --]]
function random_password(k)
    local alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    local n = string.len(alphabet)
    local pw = {}
    for i = 1, k
    do
        pw[i] = string.byte(alphabet, math.random(n))
    end
    return string.char(table.unpack(pw))
end
```

Comment: Or this simpler variant: `for i = 1, k do local j=math.random(n); pw[i] = string.sub(alphabet,j,j) end return table.concat(pwd)`

Comment: Thank you, to be honest, I figured it out a few minutes before you answered but I left it open to see if anyone had a better way.